# Erro ao instalar exp via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Erro ao instalar exp via npm**

Expo is a set of tools, libraries and services which let you build native iOS and Android apps by writing JavaScript.

**ERRO!**

```
npm install exp -g
```

Mesmo instalando com sudo e tudo mas, continua dando o error, embaixo a saida do erro.

```
@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.4.5 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux

node platform.js

/usr/bin/exp -> /usr/lib/node_modules/exp/bin/exp.js

 spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/spawn-sync

node postinstall


@expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/@expo/ngrok

node ./postinstall.js

ngrok - error unpacking binary { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/@expo/ngrok/bin/ngrok'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/@expo/ngrok/bin/ngrok' }
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.4.5 (node_modules/exp/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.4.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall: `node ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-22T14_18_35_034Z-debug.log
}
```

Alguém já se deparou com esse erro?

Comment: Isso parece problema de permissão de acesso. Tenta dar permissão no diretório antes de tentar instalar.

Comment: @Viana já de permissão de 777 para todas as pastas a parte de node_modules, mas nada resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução**

```
for node installs on linux mint and ubuntu where it gets installed in /usr/bin/node and /usr/lib/node_modules, this did the trick for me:

$sudo yarn global add ngork --modules-folder /usr/lib/node_modules   
$sudo yarn global add exp --modules-folder /usr/lib/node_modules
```

Usei a mesmo solução para o meu archlinux

[Poste original](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/429)